# Probability density function from the inverse of another function

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

Given the function:

$$f(x) = 1/sin(x)$$

where *x* is the angular interval 0  ≤ *x* < 1.5708 (in radians). I want to obtain a probability density function which represents the inverse case of *f*(*x*). 
Programmatically, I can obtain a mass function which is an approximation to the desired pdf over a fixed range, 0 ≤ *x* < 1.5533 [0-89°], using the following hack (which is satisfactory for my code application):

```
% in matlab code
% find f(x) at 1 degree intervals and plot 
fx = zeros(90,1);
theta = 0;
for i = 1:90;
    fx(i) = 1/sind(theta);
    theta = theta+1;
end
plot(0:89,fx);
```

[image: f(x)]

```
% hack desired pdf
fx = zeros(90,1);
theta = 0;
for i = 1:90;
    fx(i) = 1/cosd(theta);
    theta = theta+1;
end
maxi = fx(90);
% flip dimension of the reverse sign of fx
fxF = flipdim(-fx+maxi,1);
% normalize
xPDF =  fxF/sum(fxF(:)); 
% plot
plot(0:89, xPDF);
```

[image: form of the target PDF]

What I require is the probability density function which equates to the distribution displayed in the second graph. I am more of a programmer than a mathematician so I would appreciate it if you go easy on me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not too sure what you mean, the second function that you are drawing is some sort of a transformation on $f(x) =\frac 1 {cosx} $. Is what you want a "flipped" version of the original? Because that's not necessarily the same as the inverse.

Comment: To clarify the inverse of your original function is $f(x) = arcsin( 1/x )  $ whereas your second function is a bit different, can you elaborate what does flipdim does?

Comment: Apologies for my mis-use of the term 'inverse' (I used it for want of a better term).

Comment: flipdim merely flips the order of a vector: In the code example I am just computing the mirrored equivalent of *f(x*) using *cosx*, then flipping the vector order, the sign, translating the vector fx then normalising to get the form of the PDF function I'm after (which is a total hack).

Comment: In the simplest terms, I guess that I want a PDF whose growth is proportional to the decay in *f(x*) over the interval 0 ≤ x < 1.5708.

Comment: Admittedly I may be posing the question poorly

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you code correctly, you get for the second one something among the lines of 
$$
f(x) = g( \frac 1 {sin(90} - \frac 1 {sin(x)}) 
$$
Where $g$ is your **flipdim** function. 
If understand what it does correctly your result should be along the lines of
$$
f(x) = - \frac 1 {sin(90} + \frac 1 {sin(x)}
$$

Though if I were you, I'd use 
$$
f(x)  = \frac 1 {sin(x)} - 1
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe that the *f(x*) = 1/sin(*x*)-1 will only result in the positive translation of the original function, *f(x*) = 1/sin(*x*) in the *y* axis.

Comment: "Is what you want a "flipped" version of the original" - this is pretty much exactly what I want.